# Java Chat program (server and client) hangs and nothing happens,

Tags: java, sockets

I have made two simple java programs: server chat and client chat. I do not see any errors in the codes of each java file but the programs hang when I try to connect the client program to the server program.

Here is the server side code:

```
package com.server;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection = null;

/**
 * Creates new form sever
 */
public Server() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    startRunning();
}

 //setup and run the server
public void startRunning(){
    try{
        //serversocket(port,queueLength)
        server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
        while(true){
            try{
               waitForConnection();
               setupStreams();
               whileChatting();
            }catch(EOFException eofException){
                showMessage("\n Server ended the connection!");
            }finally{
                closeCrap();
            }
        }
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//wait for connection, then display connection 
private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
    showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect...\n");
    connection = server.accept();
    showMessage("Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress()); 
}

//get stream to send and receive data
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    showMessage("\n Streams are now setup!\n");
}

//during the chat conversation
private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    String message = "SERVER -  You are now connected! ";
    sendMessage(message);
    ableToType(true);
    do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotfoundException){
            showMessage("\n idk wtf the user sent!");
        }
    }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));
}

//close streams and sockets after chatting
private void  closeCrap(){
    showMessage("\n Closing connections...\n");
    ableToType(false);
    try{
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }catch(NullPointerException nullPointerException){
        showMessage("You are trying to close something not opened");
    }
}

//send message to clients
private void sendMessage(String message){
    try{
        output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\nSEVER - " + message);
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        chatWindow.append("\n Error: i cant send that message");
    }
}

//updates chatWindow
private void showMessage(final String text){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    chatWindow.append(text);
                }
            }
    );
}

//let the user type stuff
private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                userText.setEditable(tof);
            }
        }
    );
}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>



    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Server().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the client side code:

```
package com.client;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class client extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection con;
int b;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private String message = "";
private String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
private Socket connection;

public client() {
    initComponents();
}

private void statusMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    startRunning(); 
}                                   

//start chat system
public void startRunning(){
    try{
        connectToServer();
        setupStreams();
        whileChatting();
    }catch(EOFException eofException){
        eofException.printStackTrace();
        showMessage("\n Client terminated the connection");
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        closeCrap();
    }
}

//connect to server
private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
    showMessage("\nAttempting connection...\n");
    try{
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP),6789);
        showMessage("Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());            
    }catch(ConnectException connectException){
        showMessage("IP not available or port busy");
    }
}

//streams for seding and receiving
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    try{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        showMessage("\n Streams are good to go \n");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("there was error with output or input");
    }

}

//while chatting with server
private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    ableToType(true);
    do{
       try{
           message = (String) input.readObject();
           showMessage("\n" + message);
           System.out.println(message);
       }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotfoundException){
           showMessage("\n I dont know what that object is");
       }catch(EOFException eofException){
           showMessage("\nThere was an error with  collecting input ");
       }
    }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
}

//clos all stuff
private void closeCrap() {
    showMessage("\n Closing connection...");
    ableToType(false);
    try{
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//send messages to server
private void sendMessage(String message){
    try{
        output.writeObject("CLIENT - " + message);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\nCLIENT - " + message);
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        chatWindow.append("\n Something went wrong while sending message");
    }
}

//showMessages
private void showMessage(final String m){
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    chatWindow.append(m);
                }
            }
    );
}

//allow typing
private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    userText.setEditable(tof);
                }
            }
    );
}

//showError
private void showError(String err){
    String errMsg =  err;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errMsg, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new client().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I will be very glad if someone could go through and give me some hints as to how to correct this.

Comment: This may be too simple, but do you have a firewall up?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see where exactly the problem is?

Comment: Where exactly does your server actually start to listen to the port? You have a missing `initComponents()` method which you haven't given us.

Comment: the `initComponents()` only deals with creating and naming the objects in the GUI....should i post that too here??

Comment: The server starts listening after the button `jButton1` is clicked....that calls the `startRunning()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. I have done minor reworks:

- constructors to call startRunning()
- removed invokeLater from showMessage. I think this caused freezing in your GUI. It did not print stuff properly and froze.
- couple of other minor things.

And it seems to be working ok.

My suggestion for the future is that you separate server/client from GUI.
So you can easily test them easily against each other and make it portable to handle any other User Interface.

Output:

> client: showMessage
>   Attempting connection...
>      
>   client: showMessageConnected to: 127.0.0.1
>   client: showMessage
>   Streams are good to go 
>   
>   client: showMessage
>   SERVER - SERVER -  You are now connected! 
>   SERVER - SERVER -  You are now connected!

I am attaching the code for your reference.

Server

```
package com.server;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket connection = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form sever
     */
    public Server() {
        //initComponents();
        startRunning();
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        startRunning();
    }

     //setup and run the server
    public void startRunning(){
        try{
            //serversocket(port,queueLength)
            server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
            while(true){
                try{
                   waitForConnection();
                   setupStreams();
                   whileChatting();
                }catch(EOFException eofException){
                    showMessage("\n Server ended the connection!");
                }finally{
                    closeCrap();
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //wait for connection, then display connection 
    private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
        showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect...\n");
        connection = server.accept();
        showMessage("Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress()); 
    }

    //get stream to send and receive data
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        showMessage("\n Streams are now setup!\n");
    }

    //during the chat conversation
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
        String message = "SERVER -  You are now connected! ";
        sendMessage(message);
        ableToType(true);
        do{
            try{
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage("\n" + message);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotfoundException){
                showMessage("\n idk wtf the user sent!");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));
    }

    //close streams and sockets after chatting
    private void  closeCrap(){
        showMessage("\n Closing connections...\n");
        ableToType(false);
        try{
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NullPointerException nullPointerException){
            showMessage("You are trying to close something not opened");
        }
    }

    //send message to clients
    private void sendMessage(String message){
        try{
            output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message);
            output.flush();
            showMessage("\nSEVER - " + message);
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            System.out.println("\n Error: i cant send that message");
    //        chatWindow.append("\n Error: i cant send that message");
        }
    }

    //updates chatWindow
    private void showMessage(final String text){
        // INVOKE LATER REMOVED.
        System.out.println(text);;
    }

    //let the user type stuff
    private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
        // INVOKE LATER REMOVED.
                    System.out.println("userText -> setEditable off");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>



        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Server().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Client:

```
package com.client;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class client extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection con;
    int b;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private String message = "";
    private String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
    private Socket connection;

    public client() {
        //initComponents();
        startRunning();
    }

    private void statusMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        startRunning(); 
    }                                   

    //start chat system
    public void startRunning(){
        try{
            connectToServer();
            setupStreams();
            whileChatting();
        }catch(EOFException eofException){
            eofException.printStackTrace();
            showMessage("\n Client terminated the connection");
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            closeCrap();
        }
    }

    //connect to server
    private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
        showMessage("\nAttempting connection...\n");
        try{
            connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP),6789);
            showMessage("Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());            
        }catch(ConnectException connectException){
            showMessage("IP not available or port busy");
        }
    }

    //streams for seding and receiving
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
        try{
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            showMessage("\n Streams are good to go \n");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("there was error with output or input");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //while chatting with server
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
        ableToType(true);
        do{
           try{
               message = (String) input.readObject();
               showMessage("\n" + message);
               System.out.println(message);
           }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotfoundException){
               showMessage("\n I dont know what that object is");
           }catch(EOFException eofException){
               showMessage("\nThere was an error with  collecting input ");
           }
        }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
    }

    //clos all stuff
    private void closeCrap() {
        showMessage("\n Closing connection...");
        ableToType(false);
        try{
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //send messages to server
    private void sendMessage(String message){
        try{
            output.writeObject("CLIENT - " + message);
            output.flush();
            showMessage("\nCLIENT - " + message);
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            // chatWindow.append("\n Something went wrong while sending message");
        }
    }

    //showMessages
    private void showMessage(final String m){
        // INVOKE LATER REMOVED.
                        System.out.println("client: showMessage" + m);
    }

    //allow typing
    private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
        // INVOKE LATER REMOVED.
        System.out.println("userText.setEditable: " + tof);
    }

    //showError
    private void showError(String err){
        String errMsg =  err;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errMsg, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new client().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Vito, in the code i posted the client and server are all in separate packages. the program freezes when there is a connection. But when disconnected the stuffs are printed to the `chatWindow`. Your approach works fine but the server can not send messages to the client and vice versa.

Comment: I am not quite sure what problem do you refer to. I see that the messages are passed and printed. My suggestion is that you remove invokeLater() stuff. It causes the freezing. Replace whatever is in the chat with the console. It works on my end. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: your codes works but it only prints out to the cmd line....     I managed to get the program to work by removing the startRunning method from starting with the click of a button and placed it just before the close of the main method

Comment: @gray4webs I used printing to console to check for what you had asked (ie. hanging). I proved it was not hanging. Was my answer of any help for you? If it was - you can upvote it :)